# onClick and addEventListner? nothing works

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, onclick

So, I'm trying to get a deck of cards created with javascript (via json api) do display when the link "audiobooks" is clicked. But it's not working. I've tried onclick in the a-tagg calling the function, tried reversing it and calling the a-tagg and applying eventListner... What am I doing wrong here? i've looked online for a solution but now I'm stuck.

Link to stripped down fiddle:jsFiddle

```js
//PAGE- Audiobooks

function loadJsonAudiobook() {
    let yhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    yhttp.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=war+audiobooks", true);
    yhttp.send();
    
    yhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (yhttp.readystate === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && yhttp.status === 200) {
    let audiobookData = JSON.parse(yhttp.responseText);
    displayAudiobookCards (audiobookData);
} // end of if
}; // end of onreadystate
} // end of loadJsonAudiobook


// DISPLAY CARDS (audiobooks link)  
function displayAudiobookCards(audiobookData) {
    
    var audioDeck = document.getElementById("card2Container");

    var audioRow = document.createElement("div");
    audioRow.setAttribute("class", "row text-center");

    for (var y = 0; y < audiobookData.items.length; y++) {
        if (y === 12) {break;}
        var audioColumn = document.createElement("div");
        audioColumn.setAttribute("class", "col-md-4 pb-1 pb-md-0");

        var audioCard = document.createElement("div");
        audioCard.setAttribute("class", "card");

        var audioImage = document.createElement("img");
        audioImage.setAttribute("class", "card-img-top mx-auto d-block");
        audioImageImage.setAttribute("src", audiobookData.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail);

        var audioBody = document.createElement("div");
        audioBody.setAttribute("class", "card-body");

        var audioTitle = document.createElement("h5");
        audioTitle.setAttribute("class", "card-title");
        audioTitle.innerHTML += audiobookData.items[i].volumeInfo.title;
        
        var audioSub = document.createElement("p");
        audioSub.setAttribute("class", "card-subtitle");
        audioSub.innerHTML += audiobookData.items[i].volumeInfo.authors;

        var audioText = document.createElement("p");
        audioText.setAttribute("class", "card-text");
        audioText.innerHTML += audiobookData.items[i].volumeInfo.description;

        var audioFooter = document.createElement("div");
        audioFooter.setAttribute("class", "card-footer");

        var audioReadBtn = document.createElement("button");
        audioReadBtn.innerHTML += "Read More";
        audioReadBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
        audioReadBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-block");

        var audioBuyBtn = document.createElement("button");
        audioBuyBtn.innerHTML += "Add to Cart";
        audioBuyBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
        audioBuyBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-block");
        
        audioBody.append(audioTitle);
        audioBody.append(audioSub);
        audioBody.append(audioText);
        audioFooter.append(audioReadBtn);
        audioFooter.append(audioBuyBtn);
        audioCard.append(audioImage);
        audioCard.append(audioBody);
        audioCard.append(audioFooter);
        audioColumn.append(audioCard);
        audioRow.append(audioColumn);

    }; //end of for-loop
    audioDeck.append(audioRow);
}; //end of displayAudiobookCards
```

```html
<li class="nav-item mx-1 mx-sm-0"><a id="audiobook" onclick="loadJsonAudiobook()" class="nav-link" href="#">Audiobooks</a></li>
```

`
https://jsfiddle.net/2fqygwmn/1/#&togetherjs=1pczIUhGJnhttps://jsfiddle.net/2fqygwmn/1/#&togetherjs=1pczIUhGJn

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: You can make a runnable on-site example using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Some older questions have fiddle links before snippet was added but for new ones put a snippet as @T.J.Crowder suggests which reproduces the issue here!

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - And even older questions with fiddle links **should** have all the code in the question itself, even if they *also* link to a fiddle. (And SherardiaAvensis -  doing that is still okay, though Snippets make it easier to help you. The key thing is that the code is in the quesiton.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for that clarification of my comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly typos, here goes.

1. readystate is readyState so

`if (yhttp.readystate === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && yhttp.status === 200) {`

Should be

`if (yhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && yhttp.status === 200) {`

2. You must have copy and pasted the i in your for loop but you used y as the index variable. So accessing `audiobookData.items[i]` should be `audiobookData.items[y]`

Your complete code should look something like this

```
 function loadJsonAudiobook() {
    let yhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    yhttp.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=war+audiobooks", true);
    yhttp.send();

    yhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (yhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && yhttp.status === 200) {
            let audiobookData = JSON.parse(yhttp.responseText);
            displayAudiobookCards (audiobookData);
        } // end of if
    }; // end of onreadystate
} // end of loadJsonAudiobook


// DISPLAY CARDS (audiobooks link)  
function displayAudiobookCards(audiobookData) {

    var audioDeck = document.getElementById("card2Container");

    var audioRow = document.createElement("div");
    audioRow.setAttribute("class", "row text-center");

    for (var y = 0; y < audiobookData.items.length; y++) {
        if (y === 12) {break;}
        var audioColumn = document.createElement("div");
        audioColumn.setAttribute("class", "col-md-4 pb-1 pb-md-0");

        var audioCard = document.createElement("div");
        audioCard.setAttribute("class", "card");

        var audioImage = document.createElement("img");
        audioImage.setAttribute("class", "card-img-top mx-auto d-block");
        audioImage.setAttribute("src", 
 audiobookData.items[y].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail);

        var audioBody = document.createElement("div");
        audioBody.setAttribute("class", "card-body");

         var audioTitle = document.createElement("h5");
        audioTitle.setAttribute("class", "card-title");
        audioTitle.innerHTML += audiobookData.items[y].volumeInfo.title;
    
        var audioSub = document.createElement("p");
        audioSub.setAttribute("class", "card-subtitle");
        audioSub.innerHTML += audiobookData.items[y].volumeInfo.authors;

        var audioText = document.createElement("p");
        audioText.setAttribute("class", "card-text");
        audioText.innerHTML += audiobookData.items[y].volumeInfo.description;

        var audioFooter = document.createElement("div");
        audioFooter.setAttribute("class", "card-footer");

        var audioReadBtn = document.createElement("button");
        audioReadBtn.innerHTML += "Read More";
        audioReadBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
        audioReadBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-block");

        var audioBuyBtn = document.createElement("button");
        audioBuyBtn.innerHTML += "Add to Cart";
        audioBuyBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
        audioBuyBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-block");
    
        audioBody.append(audioTitle);
        audioBody.append(audioSub);
        audioBody.append(audioText);
        audioFooter.append(audioReadBtn);
        audioFooter.append(audioBuyBtn);
        audioCard.append(audioImage);
        audioCard.append(audioBody);
        audioCard.append(audioFooter);
        audioColumn.append(audioCard);
        audioRow.append(audioColumn);

    }; //end of for-loop
    audioDeck.append(audioRow);
}; //end of displayAudiobookCards
```

Oh and make sure you have an element with id card2Container so when calling
`document.getElementById("card2Container")` it won't return null.

Comment: wow... just wow. this is embarrassing. Haha! Sometimes you just need a new pair of eyes, min were obviously not doing their job here. Thanks so much! You're a gem! (and yes i've copied the for-loop from another part of js and I do have a div-tagg with id card2Container, i just forgot to put it in the post)